# How to load 3.xx kernel in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, kernel

I have installed Ubuntu Server from 14.04.5 distro. It comes with version 4.4 of the kernel which (as I know) is incompatible with 'fglrx' video driver. Then I installed version 3.13.0-125 of the kernel manually. But! It fails to load. First, it hangs with the message 'Configuring network'. Second, it doesn't react on keyboard.

Comment: Why do you need fglrx with a Server???

Comment: @Pilot6:
to run OpenCL-required software, while AMDGPU-PRO doesn't support 'older' cards (as opposed to Windows Catalyst driver). Other options?

Comment: You need to use a [14.04.1 ISO](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04.1/), which is the latest with the 3.13 kernel.